# Realizar subtração usando funções de agregação

Tags: sql, query

Possuo uma tabela **imoveis** com os campos de **código**, **preço** e **área**. Eu preciso descobrir qual é a diferença de preços entre o maior e o menor imóvel da tabela (em questão de área).

Eu tentei isto, mas é feita a diferença entre o maior e menor preço da tabela, independente da área.

```
select (max(vl_preco)) - (min(vl_preco)) from imovel;
```

Com a seguinte query eu tenho o retorno dos preços pela ordem da área, mas precisaria fazer a subtração do último valor com o primeiro apresentado.

```
select max(vl_preco) from imovel group by nr_areatotal;
```

Tem algum jeito de fazer isso ou alguma maneira mais eficiente?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Ué, já tentou misturar os dois conceitos? `select (max(vl_preco)) - (min(vl_preco)) from imovel group by nr_areatotal;`

Comment: Já, mas ele retorna um resultado para cara imóvel encontrado. E eu sinceramente não sei o que são esses valores, mas nenhum bate com a diferença de valores do maior imóvel com o menor.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cec83/1 Falta colocar o `nr_areatotal` no SELECT também.